# Why do my Dialog Box Classes write to each other?

Tags: python, wxpython, modal-dialog, duplicates

I'm working on a program that is going to be used with a Time Motion study.  There are times that the user may have to create add new objects (Observer, Subject, Clinic).  In order to accomplish this I have employed the use of a modal dialog box, (since all data is associated to a subject, observer, and clinic).

I have created a general class for the dialog boxes, and then just create an instance of this class for each dialog box.  However, when the user creates a new entry with one class, and then the other, the previous classes input is created again, thus causing a duplicate in data.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on and looking for some help:

Here's my general dialog box class:

```
class NewDataDialog(wx.Dialog):
def __init__(self, parent, id, title, databoxes, pubsubmessage):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self,parent,id, title)

    self.databoxes = databoxes
    self.pubsubmessage = pubsubmessage
    # MainSizer Creation
    self.MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    # Top Label Creation and addition to Main Sizer
    self.TopLbl = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Create a " + title)
    self.TopLbl.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
    self.MainSizer.Add(self.TopLbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

    self.SubSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    # Labels
    self.LblSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for lbl in databoxes:
        self.lbl = wx.StaticText(self, -1, lbl+":")
        self.LblSizer.Add(self.lbl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)


    self.SubSizer.Add(self.LblSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)

    # Boxes
    self.InputSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    for lbl in databoxes:
        self.box = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
        self.InputSizer.Add(self.box, 0, wx.ALL, 1)

    self.SubSizer.Add(self.InputSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_LEFT, 5)
    self.MainSizer.Add(self.SubSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

    # Save and Cancel Buttons
    self.buttonSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.saveButton = SaveButton(self, 'Save')
    self.cancelButton = CancelButton(self, 'Cancel')
    self.buttonSizer.Add(self.saveButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    self.buttonSizer.Add(self.cancelButton, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

    self.MainSizer.Add(self.buttonSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)
    self.SetSizerAndFit(self.MainSizer)

    pub.subscribe(self.cancelbutton, "mainpanel.CancelButton")
    pub.subscribe(self.savebutton, "mainpanel.SaveButton")

def cancelbutton(self, message):

    self.Close()


def savebutton(self, message):

    results = []

    for lbl in self.databoxes:
        results.append(self.box.GetValue())

    pub.sendMessage(self.pubsubmessage, results)
    self.Close()

class CancelButton(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.dialogbutton = wx.Button(self, -1, title)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonActivate, self.dialogbutton)


    def OnButtonActivate(self, event):

        pub.sendMessage("mainpanel.CancelButton", "")


class SaveButton(CancelButton):

    def OnButtonActivate(self, event):

        pub.sendMessage("mainpanel.SaveButton", "")
```

And here's the creation of each instance of the dialog box:

```
def newsubject(self, message):

    titles = ["Full Name", "Initials", "Job Title"]
    self.newsubject = NewDataDialog(self, 0, 'New Subject', titles, "MainPanel.NewSubjectDialog.Save")
    self.newsubject.ShowModal()

def newobserver(self, message):

    titles = ["Full Name", "Initials"]
    self.newobserver = NewDataDialog(self, 1, 'New Observer', titles, "MainPanel.NewObserverDialog.Save")
    self.newobserver.ShowModal()

def newclinic(self, message):

    titles = ["Clinic Name","Location","Initials"]
    self.newclinic = NewDataDialog(self, 2, 'New Clinic', titles, "MainPanel.NewClinicDialog.Save")
    self.newclinic.ShowModal()
```

Where each of these are called if the user selects a button labeled for the action that they desire. I.e. "Create a New Observer" will run the function `newobserver`

For a full view of the code you can look [here](http://pastebin.com/s5720aFN).  *Note: Not all comments are correctly annotated, and there are other files as a part of this and so therefore won't run, but will hopefully give you a little more insight to what's going on*

Comment: And how real objects are connected with this code? Can't see any code for new objects creation just forms. Or I've missed something?

Comment: What is `pub`? It looks like it might be a global object that accumulates references to the `savebutton` methods of every `NewDataDialog` object you create. If something causes those accumulated references to be called later, that would explain duplicate data. I guess you need an `unsubscribe` at some point

Comment: @slowdog it's [pubsub](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/) used for moving data between classes and files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing references to the `NewDataDialog` instances in `self.newsubject`, `self.newobserver` and `self.newclinic`. This means the objects continue to exist, and to listen for `"mainpanel.SaveButton"` events, even after the `newsubject`, `newobserver`, and `newclinic` methods exit. Once you've opened one of each kind of dialog box, there will always be three such objects hanging around, and each `"mainpanel.SaveButton"` event will cause all three to try and save their data.

If you did not store these references, then the objects would [apparently](http://pubsub.sourceforge.net/apidocs/apidocs.html#listener-lifetime) be garbage collected, and the subscriptions automatically removed. If you do need to store the references, then you should arrange for an `unsubscribe` to happen after the `ShowModal()`.

```
def cancelbutton(self, message):

    pub.unsubscribe(self.savebutton, "mainpanel.SaveButton")
    pub.unsubscribe(self.cancelbutton, "mainpanel.CancelButton")
    self.Close()


def savebutton(self, message):

    results = []

    for lbl in self.databoxes:
        results.append(self.box.GetValue())

    pub.sendMessage(self.pubsubmessage, results)
    pub.unsubscribe(self.savebutton, "mainpanel.SaveButton")
    pub.unsubscribe(self.cancelbutton, "mainpanel.CancelButton")
    self.Close()
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Though I was referring to your comment anyway, so you deserve the credit